# CSS - Outer element width not being overwritten

Tags: html, css

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zem4c7wf/

So what I'm trying to do is have a text element with a short width restriction, like it existed within a left pane. (`.under` & `width: 160px` in this example)

When you hover over it, another text element will display over it (`.over` & `width: 300px`). However, the `.over` text element does not respect the width I gave it, and instead is going off of it's parent width (`.under`)

I tried using a z-index and position: absolute, but I can't get the hover text to display fully.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Note: I can't get JSFiddle to mimic the behavior I'm seeing on my site, but when trying to make the overflow visible, it just adds a horizontal scrollbar rather than bringing the hover text completely to the forefront. (Hover text is the black line)

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding `overflow: visible;` when the `.under` div is hovered.

**CSS**

```
.under:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```css
.under {
  width: 160px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.over {
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 1;

    width: 300px;
}

.under:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}

.under:hover .over {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="under">
Something long and cut off
  <span class="over">
    Something long and NOT cut off
  </span>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zem4c7wf/4/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried your solution, but unfortunately couldn't make it work. I tried copying over the CSS from my site exactly, but failed to get JSFiddle to replicate the behavior I'm seeing.

When making the overflow visible on the hover text, instead of actually coming to the forefront, it adds a horizontal scrollbar. I added a screenshot to the original post. I'll see if I can get JSFiddle to behave.

Comment: Sounds like there may be some conflicting styles in another part of your code. Let me know if there's anything else I can do to help!

Answer (score 0):

just remove the overflow: hidden from the class ".under"

Comment: The OP wants the text to be cut off when it's the original text, which is why they're using `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: OP? this was not mentioned in the question

Comment: OP means "original poster". And, **_So what I'm trying to do is have a text element with a short width restriction_**.